# Python: ConfigParser with wildcards in section names

Tags: python, configparser

Does anybody have an elegant way of handling wildcards in the section names?

What I was looking was something like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
foo = 1
bar = 2

[ABC???]
foo = 11

[XYZ???]
bar = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like

```
[s for s in my_config_parser.sections() if s.startswith('ABC')]
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear in my original posting. I read the config file, then I read a second file (CSV) and I want to apply values from the config to the columns in CSV files based on the index field.

Comment: so you are using defaults from the INI file to fill in blanks in the CSV file?